# List whose elements depend on the previous ones

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a list of increasing integers. If the difference of 2 consecutive numbers is less than a threshold, then we index them by the same number, starting from 0. Otherwise, we increase the index by 1.

For example: for the list (1,2,5,7,8,11,15,16,20) and the threshold = 3, the output will be: (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4).

Here is my code:

```
  val listToGroup = List(1,2,5,7,8,11,15,16,20)
  val diff_list = listToGroup.sliding(2,1).map{case List(i, j) => j-i}.toList

  val thres = 2

  var j=0
  val output_ = for(i <- diff_list.indices) yield {
    if (diff_list(i) > thres ) {
      j += 1
    }
    j
  }
  val output = List.concat(List(0), output_)
```

I'm new to Scala and I feel the list is not used efficiently. How can this code be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the mutable variable by using `scanLeft` to get a more idiomatic code:

```
val output = diff_list.scanLeft(0) { (count, i) => 
  if (i > thres) count + 1
  else count
}
```

Your code shows some constructs which are usually avoided in Scala, but common when coming from procedural langugues, like: `for(i <- diff_list.indices) ... diff_list(i)` can be replaced with `for(i <- diff_list)`.

Other than that, I think your code is efficient - you need to traverse the list anyway and you do it in `O(N)`. I would not worry about efficiency here, more about style and readability.

My rewrite to how I think it would be more natural in Scala for the whole code would be:

```
val listToGroup = List(1,2,5,7,8,11,15,16,20)

val thres = 2

val output = listToGroup.zip(listToGroup.drop(1)).scanLeft(0) { case (count, (i, j)) => 
  if (j - i > thres) count + 1
  else count
}
```

My adjustments to your code:

- I use `scanLeft` to perform the result collection construction
- I prefer `x.zip(x.drop(1))` over `x.sliding(2, 1)` (constructing tuples seems a bit more efficient than constructing collections). You could also use `x.zip(x.tail)`, but that does not handle empty `x`
- I avoid the temporary result `diff_list`

Comment: May I ask what does the "0" in the scanLeft(0) do? When I try different numbers, or even string, it always gives me the same result.

Comment: The 0 here is the initial value for the `count`. Check documentation for `foldLeft` and `scanLeft` (`foldLeft` shows the same idea in a simpler setting).

Comment: "it always gives me the same result" Something must be wrong in how you compile the code, then. It should not give the same result (and it does not to me when I try).

Comment: You are right, I've compiled the wrong code. The arguments of scanLeft are clear to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```scala
val listToGroup = List(1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 11, 15, 16, 20)

val thres = 2

listToGroup
  .sliding(2)
  .scanLeft(0)((a, b) => { if (b.tail.head - b.head > thres) a + 1 else a })
  .toList
  .tail
```

You don't need to use mutable variable, you can achieve the same with scanLeft.